# How do I run Java as a service on Ubuntu?

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, service, upstart

So after 2 days (yes I'm a complete rookie when it comes to servers) trying to get this working I give up and turn to SO for help :)

I want to start my java app on start, log to a logfile. That's it :)

```
start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [!2345]


#Respawn the process if it crashes
#If it respawns more than 10 times in 5 seconds stop
respawn
respawn limit 10 5

expect fork

script
    cd /home/ubuntu/admin/
    mvn spring-boot:run > /var/log/upstart/admin.log 2>&1
end script
```

Running "sudo start admin" works and I get "admin start/running" in console.. No log is created and the java app is not started.. ?

What am I missing?

How do I run Java as a service on Ubuntu?

Comment: Could you confirm that /home/ubuntu/admin/pom.xml exists  ?

Comment: It does.. I will get someone to take a look at this in 2016.. now it's time for X-mas ;)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It may be more appropriate on the related sites http://askubuntu.com OR http://ServerFault.com. Consider using the flag link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it there. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter how is it not programming? Service configuration is part of the product source in many cases.  I debated the same thing myself and realized it's completely valid as a question here.

Comment: This is not about programming, this is about configuring a server using script - the question isn't about software development itself. I guess you'll find your answer faster on e.g. http://superuser.com or http://serverfault.com

Comment: @AlainO'Dea : I agree, there's no easy line. While I used to advocate strictly for `if/else` sort of coding issues, I realize that is too narrow AND there really isn't a StackExchange site to handle many issues that crop up. But when I see a lot of linux/ubuntu specific key words in a Q, my vote is to send questioner to sites as I have mentioned above. My vote to close is strictly MHO, so I leave it to the votes AND good answers to decide if the Q should really be closed or not. Good answer, by the way :-). Good luck to all.

Comment: @RobertGoldwein the line is blurry for sure. Where the OP stays inside SO for me is by asking for help with programming a server configuration to bundle with a product. I was on the fence about ServerFault or AskUbuntu as their audiences would likely balk at configuration for software delivery and punt the OP back here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't mean to sidetrack, but I've deployed Java applications on Ubuntu in production since 2010 and had very little success with Upstart.  I use init.d scripts and start-stop-daemon.  Side bonus: it works on more distros.

Create **/etc/init.d/my-java-app**:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# my-java-app My Java App
#
# chkconfig: - 80 05
# description: Enable My Java Application
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          my-java-app
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $network
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $network
# Default-Start: 2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop: 0 1 6
# Description:       My Java Application
# Short-Description: Enable My Java Application
### END INIT INFO

DESC="my java app"
NAME=my-java-app
PIDFILE=/var/run/$NAME.pid
RUN_AS=ubuntu
WORK_DIR=/home/ubuntu/admin
DAEMON=/usr/bin/mvn
DAEMON_OPTS="spring-boot:run"

# Read configuration variable file if it is present
[ -r /etc/default/$NAME ] && . /etc/default/$NAME

# Load the VERBOSE setting and other rcS variables
. /lib/init/vars.sh

# Define LSB log_* functions.
# Depend on lsb-base (>= 3.2-14) to ensure that this file is present
# and status_of_proc is working.
. /lib/lsb/init-functions

do_start() {
    start-stop-daemon --start --quiet --make-pidfile --pidfile $PIDFILE \
        --background \
        --chuid $RUN_AS \
        --chdir $WORK_DIR \
        --exec $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
}

do_stop() {
    start-stop-daemon --stop --quiet --pidfile $PIDFILE
    if [ -e $PIDFILE ]
        then rm $PIDFILE
    fi
}

case "$1" in
    start)
    echo -n "Starting $DESC: $NAME"
    do_start
    echo "."
    ;;
    stop)
    echo -n "Stopping $DESC: $NAME"
    do_stop
    echo "."
    ;;
    restart)
    echo -n "Restarting $DESC: $NAME"
    do_stop
    sleep 1
    do_start
    echo "."
    ;;
    status)
    status_of_proc -p $PIDFILE "$DAEMON" "$NAME" && exit 0 || exit $?
    ;;
    *)
    echo "usage: $NAME {start|stop|restart}"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Make it belong to root, make it executable, and set it up to run on startup with:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/init.d/my-java-app
sudo chmod 755 /etc/init.d/my-java-app
sudo update-rc.d my-java-app defaults
```

To start the service you can run:

```
sudo service my-java-app start
```

To stop the service you can run:

```
sudo service my-java-app stop
```

This is based on a simplified version of the **/etc/init.d/skeleton** file included by Ubuntu.

The [man page for **start-stop-daemon**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man8/start-stop-daemon.8.html) is worth looking at if you want to tweak this further.b

Comment: Big thanks for your suggestion! Will try it out asap! :)

Comment: @Mackelito any issues, just reply here and we can jump on a chat if need be.

Comment: Thx! :) Is there a way to log things "out of the box" or do I need to write some kind of wrapper?

Comment: @Mackelito log4j, slf4j, or logback (Java logging frameworks) would be my choices. Write their logs to **/var/log/my-java-app/*.log**.  If you want to improve security change RUN_AS to a specific user and give it write access to that folder.

Comment: I think that the problem is that I need to be in the correct folder when running the mvn command...

Comment: Right now I'm getting "adminstart-stop-daemon: unable to stat /usr/bin/mvn/spring-boot:run (Not a directory)"

Comment: @Mackelito you might need the **--chdir /home/ubuntu/admin** option. I've got to halt for now or I'll be killed.

Comment: "start-stop-daemon: unable to open pidfile '/var/run/admin.pid' for writing (Permission denied)" logged in as "ubuntu" user. Is it safe to change permissions on that file?

Comment: @Mackelito **start-stop-daemon** should be able to write the PID file as root before dropping privileges to **ubuntu** and running the **mvn spring:boot** as a daemon process.

Comment: @Mackelito you should use **sudo service my-java-app start**.  It won't work as expected if you run the init script as **ubuntu** directly.

Comment: Works great! Although I had a lot of issues with needing quotes around one of my parameters which contained spaces. This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661193/start-stop-daemon-quoted-arguments-misinterpreted